# Can't download string from specific URL by web client

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, webclient

I have this list of links where I am trying to download the string from by web client.
The other links are working fine but this specific link is having an error.

> http://www.cagolab.jp/blog/?p=28

```
using (var w = new WebClient())
{
 var json_data = w.DownloadString(adList.Link);
 ...
}
```

I am getting this error.

[image]

Can you please enlighten me of the cause of this problem?

Comment: Can you please enlighten us with the error you get?

Comment: The name of the variable `json_data` is probably not very wisely chosen for an endpoint that returns HTML markup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just tried it to run the code, to see the response and it returns the following error

> {"The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."}

And thus adding headers to the webclient might do the trick for you.

```
using(var w = new WebClient())
{
    w.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Only a test!");
    var HtmlMarkup = w.DownloadString("http://www.cagolab.jp/blog/?p=28");
}
```